# Angular4 webpack gives error when production env but works on dev env

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing an app with Angular4 and .Net Core Mvc.

When I run dev bundle script in package.json it works. Script is below:

```
del-cli wwwroot/dist/js/app && webpack --config webpack.config.dev.js --progress --profile --watch
```

When I run prod bundle script in package.json it gives error below:

> app.module.ngfactory.ts ... 'Promise' only refers to a type but is being used as a value here

Prod script is below:

```
del-cli wwwroot/dist/js/app && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json && webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && del-cli 'wwwroot/dist/js/app/**/*.js' 'wwwroot/dist/js/app/**/*.js.map' '!wwwroot/dist/js/app/bundle.js' '!wwwroot/dist/js/app/*.chunk.js' 'ClientApp/app/**/*.ngfactory.ts' 'ClientApp/app/**/*.shim.ts' 'ClientApp/app/**/*.ngsummary.json' 'ClientApp/app/**/*.ngstyle.ts'
```

My tsconfig.aot.json file is below:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./wwwroot/dist/js/app"
  },
  "types": [ "node", "lodash", "core-js" ], 
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
```

I cannot handle the error, I tried lots of things. I tried to add es2016, es2017 into lib part in tsconfig but didnot work.

Also @types/core-js version in package.json is 0.9.39.

```
"@types/core-js": "^0.9.39",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.59",
"@types/node": "^6.0.45",
"typescript": "^2.2.2"
```

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to bundle aot but normal tsconfig file affects aot bundle. So I prepared normal tsconfig file like below, problem solved:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [ "es2016", "dom" ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot/dist/js"
  ]
}
```